# PDO extremely slow on localserver

Tags: php, pdo

So basically I've got an issue with PDO. For about a couple of days now I've been working on a MVC so far so good. When I initialize PDO it takes about 1000ms to 1300ms for the webpage to load. Also I know that switching from localhost to 127.0.0.1 makes it faster. However in this case it doesn't seem to work.

```
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testDB","root","");
```

I've also tried using

```
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=testDB","root","",array(
PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

But unfortunately none have worked for me. If anyone has any tips it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that it's that line that is creating the delay?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I removed this line and it went from 1300ms to about 5ms. Then I added the regular mysql_connect method, and it loaded about 5ms to 13ms as well. It's definitely PDO.